# C function to format a string with dashes

Tags: c, string, format

Can anyone please create a c function which formats like below example by taking string anand padding lenth as input. The string should be center aligned and length of padding (dash) is constant (say 45) and string len won't exceed pad length.

example #1
--------------ABOUT------------

example #1

----------MY PAYMENTS----------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was to "help create", not "create", so here's some pseudocode for you :)

```
let numberOfDashes = TARGET_LENGTH - labelLength
let numberOfLeftDashes = numberOfDashes/2
let numberOfRightDashes = numberOfDashes - numberOfLeftDashes

let paddedString =
    repeat('-',numberOfLeftDashes)
  + labelString
  + repeat('-',numberOfRightDashes)
```

I'll leave it to you to rewrite that in C, shouldn't be hard - drop a comment if there are any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Spoiler alert!

Here's a different approach. Work out where to stick it, then stick it in.

```
char sBase[] = "---------------------------------------------";
char sInsert[] = "ABOUT";
int nStart = (strlen (sBase) - strlen (sInsert)) / 2;   // Centre of sInsert goes in centre of sBase
if (nStart >= 0)    // Make sure sInsert isn't bigger than sBase
{
    memcpy (&sBase [nStart], sInsert, strlen (sInsert));    // Stick it in
}
```

Comment: This isn't generic as the OP suggests in his comment.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, this handles all cases, including longer text than what fits into padded range:

```
char* padCentered(char* out, const char* str, const int len, const char padchar)
{
    size_t lenstr = strlen(str);
    const char* in = str;
    if (lenstr < len) {
        memset(out, padchar, len);        
    } else if (lenstr > len) {
        in = (str + (lenstr/2)) - (len/2);
        lenstr = len;
    }
    strncpy(out + ((len/2) - (lenstr/2)), in, lenstr);
    out[len] = '\0';
    return out;
}

void dopaddedstr()
{
    char buf[1024];
    printf("%s\n", padCentered(buf, "0123456789", 6, '-'));
    printf("%s\n", padCentered(buf, "0123456789", 7, '-'));
    printf("%s\n", padCentered(buf, "0123456789", 8, '-'));
    printf("%s\n", padCentered(buf, "0123456789", 10, '-'));
    printf("%s\n", padCentered(buf, "0123456789", 11, '-'));
    printf("%s\n", padCentered(buf, "0123456789", 12, '-'));
    printf("%s\n", padCentered(buf, "0123456789", 80, '-'));
}
```

outputs:

```
234567
2345678
12345678
0123456789
0123456789-
-0123456789-
-----------------------------------0123456789-----------------------------------
```